# criteria.createAlias() Multiplies Data

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using the following code to retrieve my data

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria( JobProcess.class );
cr.createAlias("sendMarcs", "sm");
cr.addOrder( Order.desc( "processedTime") );
cr.addOrder( Order.asc( "sm.ats" ) );
```

It returns all the data, but all the data appears multiple times, returning a list of size `673` when it should be a list of size `99`. I have no idea why it's happening.

And yes, I've looked at the SQL that hibernate is using and it's correct.

Also, if I remove the alias and its order, then the data appears as expected. Not multiplied, but not sorted.

JobProcess.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobprocess")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class JobProcess {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(length = 20, name="customerid")
    private String customerId;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String ATS;

    @Basic(optional=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="timeprocessed")
    private java.util.Date processedTime;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column(length = 1)
    private String state;

    @Column(length = 300)
    private String notes;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private long nos;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "jobprocessid")
    private Set<SendMarc> sendMarcs = new HashSet<SendMarc>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

SendMarc.java

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "sendmarc" )
@Cache( usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE )
public class SendMarc
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private BigInteger id;

    @Basic( optional = true )
    private BigInteger marcfileid;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    private long jobprocessid;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( length = 50 )
    private String ats;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning one object per retrieved row, as a HQL query without distinct would do. WIth a Criteria, you must use

```
cr.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Answer (score 0):

`#createAlias()` creates alias for an association it also joined. In your case, without it you simply retrieve all rows from `JobProcess` table with no joins, and in case of additional join you get different result.